# Given a keyboard command, how do you find the interactive function?

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-argument

I have a key sequence for `C-u C-c .` How would I find the function that's bound to it.  I thought it was `describe-key` but that doesn't seem to work.

Cheers

Comment: It is `describe-key` that is bound to `C-h k`. Just type `C-h k C-c .`. `C-u` is the `universal argument`, a prefix.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to get the org-mode-timestamp without hitting C-u C-c .

Comment: You should not use `C-u` in a binding.

Comment: This looks like a near duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`describe-key` is bound to `C-h k`.

If you want to know the function bound to `C-u C-c .`,
you should consider that `C-u` is a prefix to `C-c .`
and use just `C-h k C-c .`.

In this case, `C-h k C-c .` tells you that `C-c .` runs the command `org-time-stamp` and it also tells you what it does when called with a prefix argument:

> If the user specifies a time like HH:MM or if this command is
>   called with at least one prefix argument, the time stamp contains
>   the date and the time.  Otherwise, only the date is included.